# jquery selector from iframe content to object content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, iframe

I need the following:

I got a `html` document, in which I have an `iframe` and an object. Both, the iframe and the object contain separat html files.

Now I want to click a link in the iframe, and this should affect the links inside the object to hide.

How do I use `jQuery` selectors to select the links in the object html file?

Structure:

```
<html file parent>
    <iframe> html site 1 with link to click</iframe>
    <object> html site 2 with links to affect </object>
<html file parent>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Show what have you tried already, and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if the domain of the iframe is different from that of your . 
This is a javascript restriction.

Answer (score 0):

For this to possible you need to have control on the url loaded in the iframe.

If it is of same domain then you can probably do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the iframe's url try this.

First, have a look at [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). Using this, you may send an event from your iframe to the window parent target. Listening for that event in the window parent (when something in your iframe changed), you will then be able to access any element inside the `object` tag using a syntax like this:

```
$('object').contents().find('linkSelector')
```

Give your iframe an id, let's say `myIframe`:

```
<iframe id="myIframe"> html site 1 with link to click</iframe>
```

Get a reference to the iframe:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
```

Post a message from iframe:

```
myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('iframe.clicked', 'http://your-domain.here.com');
```

Handler for iframe change:

```
var handleIframeChange = function(e) {
    //
    if(e.origin == 'http://your-domain.here.com') {
        // Get reference to your `object` tag
        var objContent = $('object').contents();

        // For instance, let's hide an element with a class of `link-class-here`
        objContent.find('.link-class-here').hide();
    }
}
```

Listen on parent window for the event sent by the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('iframe.clicked', handleIframeChange, false);
```

Haven't tested it right now (did this in the past, when I had control over iframe) but it should work, but as I said, only if you can have control over the iframe.